# Same variable name with different value

Tags: php, variables

I am working in Youtube downloader project. Everything works fine except when I am trying to put these two portion of code in different place. I think for the usage of same variable name with different value in one script

```
    $i = 0;
    $ipbits = $ip = $itag = $sig = $size = '';
```

this problem occurs. I can't change the variable name because this variable name will be assigned by parse_str function in both adaptipe_array and stream_map_array with some different value. Currrently my scripts works but I think its not a good programming practice. Any suggestion for alternative to this or can it be modified in another way? Help will be appreciated.

```
/* create an array of available download formats */

    $avail_formats[] = '';
    $i = 0;
    $ipbits = $ip = $itag = $sig = $size = '';
    $expire = time(); 

    foreach($adaptive_array as $format) {
        parse_str($format);
        $avail_formats[$i]['itag'] = $itag;
        $avail_formats[$i]['size'] = $size;
        $type = explode(';',$type);
        $avail_formats[$i]['type'] = $type[0];
        $avail_formats[$i]['url'] = urldecode($url) . '&signature=' . $sig;
        parse_str(urldecode($url));
        $avail_formats[$i]['expires'] = date("G:i:s T", $expire);
        $avail_formats[$i]['ipbits'] = $ipbits;
        $avail_formats[$i]['ip'] = $ip;
        $i++;

    }



    /* create an array of available download formats */

    $avail_formats2[] = '';
    $i = 0;
    $ipbits = $ip = $itag = $sig = $quality = '';
    $expire = time(); 

    foreach($stream_map_array as $format) {
        parse_str($format);
        $avail_formats2[$i]['itag'] = $itag;
        $avail_formats2[$i]['quality'] = $quality;
        $type = explode(';',$type);
        $avail_formats2[$i]['type'] = $type[0];
        $avail_formats2[$i]['url'] = urldecode($url) . '&signature=' . $sig;
        parse_str(urldecode($url));
        $avail_formats2[$i]['expires'] = date("G:i:s T", $expire);
        $avail_formats2[$i]['ipbits'] = $ipbits;
        $avail_formats2[$i]['ip'] = $ip;
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: What does this line mean? "I think for the usage of same variable name with different value in one script"

Comment: thats mean i am using same variable name in two place for assiging different value at same time and i need the same variable name for parse_string function @RishiDua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both code portions are performing almot the same computation on different arrays, you can turn them into one function. The differences may be factored out as parameters for the function:

```
* create an array of available download formats */
function make_available_format($formats,$ename){ 
  $avail_formats[] = '';
  $i = 0;
  $ipbits = $ip = $itag = $sig = $extra = '';
  $expire = time(); 

  foreach($formats as $format) {
    parse_str($format);
    $avail_formats[$i]['itag'] = $itag;
    $avail_formats[$i][$ename] = $extra;
    $type = explode(';',$type);
    $avail_formats[$i]['type'] = $type[0];
    $avail_formats[$i]['url'] = urldecode($url) . '&signature=' . $sig;
    parse_str(urldecode($url));
    $avail_formats[$i]['expires'] = date("G:i:s T", $expire);
    $avail_formats[$i]['ipbits'] = $ipbits;
    $avail_formats[$i]['ip'] = $ip;
    $i++;
  }
  return $avail_formats;
}
```

Then use it as follow:

```
$avail_formats = make_available_format($adaptive_array,'size');
$avail_formats2 = make_available_format($stream_map_array,'quality')
);

// or maybe
$avail_formats = array(
    make_available_format($adaptive_array,'size'),
    make_available_format($stream_map_array,'quality')
);
```

You could also externalize the value of `$extra` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use functions.

```
function get_formats($input_array) {
   $avail_formats = array();
   $ipbits = $ip = $itag = $sig = $quality = '';
   $expire = time(); 

   foreach($input_array as $format) {
       $entry = array();
       parse_str($format);
       $entry['itag'] = $itag;
       $entry['quality'] = $quality;
       $type = explode(';',$type);
       $entry['type'] = $type[0];
       $entry['url'] = urldecode($url) . '&signature=' . $sig;
       parse_str(urldecode($url));
       $entry['expires'] = date("G:i:s T", $expire);
       $entry['ipbits'] = $ipbits;
       $entry['ip'] = $ip;
       $avail_formats[] = $entry;
   }
   return $avail_formats;
}


$avail_formats = get_formats($adaptive_array);
$avail_formats2 = get_formats($stream_map_array);
```